# how to insert update and delete data without using database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session

Here is my code. 
This code is insert only one value at a time but when i insert next value is will replaced last value.When we add new value it should be add in new array but this code does not work.

```
  public function index(Request $request){

    $data = $request->input();
    Session::put('name',[$data['name']]);
    Session::put('class',[$data['class']]);
    Session::put('email',[$data['email']]);

    $name = Session::get('name');
    $class = Session::get('class');
    $email = Session::get('email');

    return view('frontEnd.student.user');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Insert using session</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="{{url('/user')}}" method="post">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Class</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="class"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit"></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your current output?

Comment: What happens when you run this on different browsers? Does the code work correctly?

Comment: You are over writing the same session variable. Use different session variable name.

Comment: This code work correctly for only one value and it's output is as follows.      Array
(
    [0] => john
)
Array
(
    [0] => mca
)
Array
(
    [0] => john@gmail.com
)

Answer (score 0):

like this

v2

```
public function index(Request $request){

    $data = $request->all();
    Session::put('name', array_merge((array)Session::get('name'), [$data['name']]));
    Session::put('class',array_merge((array)Session::get('class'), [$data['class']]));
    Session::put('email',array_merge((array)Session::get('email'), [$data['email']]));

    $name = Session::get('name');
    $class = Session::get('class');
    $email = Session::get('email');

    return view('frontEnd.student.user', [
        'name' => $name,
        'class' => $class,
        'email' => $email,
    ]);
}
```

and maybe need json_encode/json_decode json_decode(Session::get('...')) and Session::put(json_encode(...))

Comment: Not working, it say's array merge first parameter is not an array. I have tried json_encode() , json_decode() too still not working. Please provide me some working code.